# Fitting Cocoa Animation into MVC/OOP patterns

Tags: cocoa-touch, animation, uiview, uiviewcontroller

MVC/OOP design patterns say you don't set a property, per se, you ask an object to set *its* property. Similarly, in Cocoa you don't tell an object when to draw itself. Your object's code has detailed HOW it will draw itself so we trust the frameworks to decide *when* (for the most part) it should draw.

But, when it comes to animation in Cocoa (specifically Cocoa-Touch) it seems that we now must take control of *when* the object draws itself from within the objects view controller. I can't send a message to a UIView subclass asking it to change some value and then leave it alone knowing it will slowly (duration = X) **animate** itself to a new position, alpha, rotation, etc. depending on the property changes. Or can I?

Basically, I'm looking for a way to set the property and then walk away. Instead, it seems, I need to wrap the code that calls the object asking it to change its property with an animation block of some sort "[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL]; ...  [UIView commitAnimations];"

I'm ending up with lots and lots of animation blocks in my view controllers and none in my view objects...I guess I'm just looking for someone to verify that this is how things are done and I'm not overlooking something. I haven't gotten much farther than the UIView animations within Cocoa-Touch, so maybe that's my problem and it's time to dig deeper?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that UIView does not animate its property changes by default the way CALayer does, but I don't think this indicates a break in MVC. It is appropriate for a Controller to instruct a View in how it should transform. That is the role of a Controller class as surely as it is appropriate for the Controller to know the correct frame for the View and even manage layout. I agree that it's a little weird that you call `-beginAnimations:context:` on the UIView class rather than on an instance, but in practice it does actually work much better that way since you may want to animate many views together.

That said, if you had a UIView subclass that managed the layout of its subviews, there would be nothing wrong with allowing that UIView to manage the animation rather than relying on a UIViewController to do it. So this is something that could go either place, but in practice it generally goes in the Controller as you've discovered.

I am using "MVC" here in the typical Cocoa sense. You're correct that this might not be appropriate in a SmallTalk program, but then [SmallTalk Controllers](http://st-www.cs.uiuc.edu/users/smarch/st-docs/mvc.html) have a much more limited role (management of user input events). Cocoa significantly expands the role of Controllers in MVC and I think it's an improvement, even if it means there are now some functions that could go in either the Controller or the View (and this is one of them).

Comment: I haven't looked into CALayers much. Not sure if they'll help me here. Sorry for my confusion...but I have a UIView subclass. I'm wondering if it's possible to set some state (say fillColor = greenColor) and then "walk away". This uiview knows how to draw itself and will fill its path with greenColor BUT it won't animate that change. It just instantly turns green. only way I can find to animate this is from setting up animation blocks in the VC.

Comment: You can get what you want by requesting the UIView's layer make the change (aView.layer.backgroundColor), since the layer will animate automatically. That said, there's nothing wrong with setting up the animation block.

Comment: In my opinion this is a violation of MVC principle which unfortunately is unavoidable in cocoa touch. The controller should decide *when* a view should change but not *how* it should change as this is view's responsibility.

Comment: @adrin, there are many ways to draw the lines in MVC, and this is just one of them. Subclassing a view in order to make it animate differently is not a fundamentally better form of MVC (nor does Cocoa prevent you from doing it if you desire). In SmallTalk MVC, a view like NSTextField would not handle its own keyboard input, since that would be the controller's job. I'm glad NeXT chose to implement MVC a different way. There are many ways to do it, and defining animations in the controller is perfectly valid, and allows the animation *itself* to be reused independent of any particularly view.